# Codeigniter trying to show results other than matches from many-to-many

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, many-to-many

I'm attempting to query a many-to-many db where I want to show users that are **not** associated with a project.

I have 3 tables, a user table, project table and a project_user_link table to house the matching user_id with project_id.

```
$tquery = $this->db->select('*')
->from('pm_project')
->where_not_in('pm_project_user_link.project_id',$project_id)
->join('pm_project_user_link', 'pm_project.id = pm_project_user_link.project_id', 'left outer')
->join('pm_users', 'pm_project_user_link.user_id = pm_users.id', 'right outer')
->get();
```

However, I'm only getting results of users that are already associated with other projects (ones already in the link table). Not all users already have projects associated with them. I'd like for all users to be shown.

When I comment out the where_not_in line, I have a result of all users. I've tried all the combos of joins I can find. I'm still noobish when it comes to mysql. I'm not sure if I need to do any further joins or if I'm going about it completely the wrong way.

My google-fu failed me in trying to find a solution. I'm positive this has been answered before, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to describe this or what this is called.

If anything is unclear, let me know.

Thank you ahead of time for any resources and help.

Edit1: I figure I should mention, the only reason I'm asking this is because I *assume* mysql can accomplish this in a very clean, clever way. In the mean time, I'm just doing it kind of dirty of knocking out users from the total user list from two queries and using an array in php.

Comment: what do you get result of `var_dump($tquery);` this may help in analyzing the query

Comment: 'object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#20 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(33) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(47) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (2) { ["first_name"]=> string(3) "PM5" ["id"]=> string(2) "13" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#22 (2) { ["first_name"]=> string(3) "PM4" ["id"]=> string(2) "14" } } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["row_data"]=> NULL }'

Those 2 results are the not in the project, but are in the link table.